# How to set a variable if undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to set the variable value when it's undefined however, I'm getting an error while trying to use vanilla javascript approach.

> Block-scoped variable 'x' used before its declaration.

What is the best approach when using typescript for setting undefined variable?

```
let x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? def_val : x;
```

Comment: `x` is _definitely_ undefined at that point because `let` is a block-scoped variable. you'll need to use `var` if `x` is to be defined in a parent block too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TypeScript can tell that `x` is definitely not defined, because it is a block-scoped variable and you can see the whole block.

If you know better than the compiler, you can separate the lines:

```
const def_val = 'default';

let x: string;
x = (typeof x === 'undefined') ? def_val : x;
```

But you might want to consider how the block scoped variable could possibly be undefined in your case (perhaps your code is not quite as simple as the example in your question).

The common use case would be more like:

```
const def_val = 'default';

function work(y: string) {
    let x = (typeof y === 'undefined') ? def_val : y;
}
```

You can also add more strict compiler options to make it less likely the value will be undefined in many cases.

## Shorthand

There is also a shorthand falsey-coalesce that may be useful:

```
const def_val = 'default';

function work(y: string) {
    let x = y || def_val;
}
```

This will replace `undefined`, `null`, `0` (zero) or `''` with the default.

Comment: Wish I had known about `y || def_val` earlier. So much annoying duplication in my code lol

Comment: @takanuva15 in my experience, if you feel like you need to duplicate your code / do other nasty things, there is probably some language feature / syntax sugar for that exact situation

Answer (score 42):

The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined).

```
x ??= default_value
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 17):

There is another a shorthand using the **Nullish coalescing operator**:

```js
const def_val = 'default';

function work(y: string) {
    let x = y ?? def_val;
}
```

This will replace only `undefined` or `null` with the default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator