# How to do this in Typescript: using the default value when the computed property does not exist?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

When using Computed Property in javascript, I can write my code like this

```
const def_val = {a:"debug",b:"info",c:"warning"};

function work(y) {
    let x = def_val[y] || def_val.a /* if y is not a or b or c */
}
```

But how to I make that work in typescript ?

```
const def_val = {a:"debug",b:"info",c:"warning"};

function work(y: string) {
    let x = def_val[y] || def_val.a;
}
```

I got the compiler error

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression
> of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string;
> c: string; }'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string'
> was found on type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }'.

I have searched SO but I can only find [How to set a variable if undefined in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328862/how-to-set-a-variable-if-undefined-in-typescript) which is not my question.

Now I changed my ts code to these, but it feels tedious compared to the original js code

```
function work(y: string) {
    let x:string
    if (y!='a' && y!='b' && y!='c') {
        x = def_val.a;
    } else {
        x = def_val[y]
    }
}
```

---- update ----

@captain-yossarian answer is one way of fix it, e.g. `const def_val: Record<string, string> = { a: "debug", b: "info", c: "warning" };`

I find the other way to fix it is to use `keyof typeof`, check here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types for further information, e.g. "In JavaScript it is fairly common to have APIs that **expect property names as parameters**, but so far it hasn’t been possible to express the type relationships that occur in those APIs.", exactly my case here!!

```
const def_val = {a:"debug",b:"info",c:"warning"};

function work(y:keyof typeof def_val) {
    let x = def_val[y] || def_val.a;

}
```

I got this answer from [How to dynamically access object property in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438346/how-to-dynamically-access-object-property-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def_val` is infered by typescript as

```js
const def_val: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
```

`y` argument has `string` type

`def_val` expects `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` as a keys. It means that typescript allows you to use only these keys with `def_val`. Since `string` type is much wider than `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` you are getting error.

`y:string` means that it allows you to pass `foo` property and `def_val['foo']` is not safe since `foo` does not exists in `def_val`.

In order to fix it, you should provide explicit type for `def_val`:

```js
const def_val: Record<string, string> = { a: "debug", b: "info", c: "warning" };

function work(y: string) {
    let x = def_val[y] || def_val.a // ok
}
```

IF you are not allowed to use explicit type on `def_val`, you can provide `def_val` as an argument to `work`:

```js
const def_val = { a: "debug", b: "info", c: "warning" };

function work<Def extends Record<string, string>>(def: Def, y: string) {
    let x = def[y] || def.a
}
work(def_val, 'foo') // ok
```

You also can use [custom typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
const def_val = { a: "debug", b: "info", c: "warning" };

const isValidKey = (key: string): key is keyof typeof def_val =>
    /a|b|c/.test(key)

const work = (y: string) => isValidKey(y) ? def_val[y] : def_val.a

work('foo') // ok
```

P.S. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) you can find documentation about using built in utility types , like `Record`, `Partial`, etc ...

Comment: I knew why I get the error and in this case the js code let x = def_val[y] || def_val.a is quite clear and straightforward while the ts code is not (if I may say so)!

Comment: Does my solution helps you to fix your ts issue ? TS is more verbose than js, it is ok. since we have types

Comment: Yes your solution has helped my fix it. Thanks. I have not accepted your answer yet (only upvote) now because I am also researching if there is other way to do it.  BTW, I updated my question too.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 sure, no problem.  I made an update

Comment: Can you provide more information or some link about Record<string, string> ?

Comment: Made an update in the answer, also here is the link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 thank you, also I did not want to look like I 'm  forcing you to accept my answer. You can wait and maybe somebody will provide you with better solution. It is ok. Have a nice day!

Comment: I find another way to fix it keyof typeof, updated my question too. Your updated answer actually mentioned it. But I didn't get that yesterday because there was too much information to digest at the first :$